# Trying to use react-router-dom to create mutlipage application in clojurescript

Tags: react-router-dom, clojurescript

I'm trying to create a multipage application with clojurescript. For the react stuff I'm using the [helix](https://github.com/lilactown/helix) library. For the reloading I'm using shadow-cljs.

When trying to use the react-router-dom like in javascript it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [app.components.home :refer [home]]
            [app.components.about :refer [about]]
            [helix.core :refer [defnc $]]
            [helix.dom :as d]
            ["react-dom" :as rdom]
            ["react-router-dom" :refer [BrowserRouter, Route, Switch]]))

(defnc app []
  (BrowserRouter
    (d/div
      (d/nav
        (d/h1 "Title")
        (d/div
          (d/a {:href "/"} "Home")
          (d/a {:href "/about"} "About")
      (Switch
        (Route {:path "/"} ($ home))
        (Route {:path "/about"} ($ about))))))

(defn ^:export run []
  (rdom/render ($ app) (js/document.getElementById "root")))
```

When running the code locally I get the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js:13232 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {MemoryRouter, Prompt, Redirect, Route, Router, StaticRouter, Switch, generatePath, matchPath, useHistory, useLocation, useParams, useRouteMatch, withRouter, BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, NavLink, props, context, refs, updater, history}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:13232)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:14134)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16991)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:17891)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3946)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:3995)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4057)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23965)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22777)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22708)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue: Because BrowserRouter, Route and Switch aren't valid React components one has to insert them with the $ macro:

```
(defnc app []
  ($ BrowserRouter
    (d/div
      (d/nav
        (d/h1 "Title")
        (d/div
          (d/a {:href "/"} "Home")
          (d/a {:href "/about"} "About")
      ($ Switch
        ($ Route {:path "/"} ($ home))
        ($ Route {:path "/about"} ($ about))))))
```